# How to accept Payments with Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

So this is my first time using Stripe to integrate payments for a website. What I am trying to do is add Stripe to my terminal for it to work correctly but I am getting an error. I have created a "Server" folder along with a "Server.js" file and when I try to initialize a new project it throws me an error.

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
Royces-MacBook-Air:Kingdom Website  roycewilliams$ $ cd server/
bash: $: command not found
Royces-MacBook-Air:Kingdom Website  roycewilliams$ cd server/
Royces-MacBook-Air:server roycewilliams$ npm init -y
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:926
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './lib/_stream_readable.js'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/readable.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/tracker-stream.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/tracker-group.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:923:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:768:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/readable.js:12:30)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:971:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:812:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/readable.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/tracker-stream.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/tracker-group.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/are-we-there-yet/index.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'
  ]
}
Royces-MacBook-Air:server royce

williams$
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to get the dependencies from npm. Type `npm i` in the same directory of the project to get the dependencies. If you don’t have npm installed you need to install it first.

Comment: realized i didn't have it downloaded thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Did you create this folder by yourself or did you clone/download it from one of Stripe's examples/repos?

If you downloaded it from somewhere, can you share the link?

Edit: The [quickstart](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart) guide also has steps that you can follow to setup your integration

Comment: No i didn't I remember doing a project awhile ago that made me change from bash to zsh. I don't know if that's the reason. I created the folder following a youtube video.